# How to delete the bootable flag of a partition

Tags: fdisk, parted

I can add a bootable flag with the `a` command of `fdisk`.

**How to do the reverse: remove the bootable flag of a partition?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **toggle** flag with `a` command.

Try the same command again and it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with the command line may be gparted is better suited for you.
Install it using

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

then open it

Once it is up and running - select the partition and then right click for "Manage Flags". After that you can select the flags accordingly.